# SQL Server 2005 - Table Functions in a Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table called PurchaseOrderDetail.

```
TABLE PurchaseOrderDetail
 PurchaseOrderDetail int,
 Comments nvarchar(500)
```

In the Comments field of each item I have a ‘;’ separated list that stores A Contract Name, Contract No, License Name, License Version.

i.e.

```
PurchaseOrderDetail     Comments 
1                      'Microsoft Office Standard 2007;12%;;'
2                      'Microsoft Visio 2007;9%;;'
```

I also have a function called Split that takes a delimiter and a string and returns a table,

So calling this 
select * from Split(';', 'Microsoft Office Standard 2007;12%;;')

returns this

```
pn           s [ column names]
1            Microsoft Office Standard 2007
2            12%
```

I need to break this information out for each PurchaseOrderDetail and show them in a report

So something like this

```
select PurchaseOrderDetailID, cn.s as ContractName, cno.s as ContractNo
from dbo.PurchaseOrderDetail as pod
join dbo.Split(';', pod.Comments) as cn on cn.pn = 1
join dbo.Split(';', pod.Comments) as cno on cno.pn = 2
```

although that doesn’t run, but I hope it suggests intent.

I’d like my results to be:

```
PurchaseOrderDetailID   ContractName                    ContractNo
1                       Microsoft Office Standard 2007  12%
```

Is it possible, or am I tackling this the wrong way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You "join" to table-valued functions using the [apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) keyword. Simply pass your fields into the function rather than using an "ON" linking expression. An example from MSDN:

```
SELECT D.deptid, D.deptname, D.deptmgrid, ST.empid, ST.empname, ST.mgrid
FROM Departments AS D
    CROSS APPLY fn_getsubtree(D.deptmgrid) AS ST;
```

OUTER APPLY is the equivalent of LEFT JOIN.

**Edit**

In your example, you could add the "cn = 1" and "cn = 2" criteria as a WHERE clause after APPLYing the function.

Comment: Thanks Matt, if you find your way in to Melbourne sometime we'll have to sort you out a beer

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why tables can have more than 1 column.  It is a pain in the but to split values out of a common column all the time!

- alter your table
- add dedicated columns for your data
- UPDATE FROM and join in the CROSS APPLY to split each row and populate the new columns
- drop the old column that contains the multiple data elements
- upgrade your save and load routines to use the new columns
- never worry about splitting the data again!

Comment: KM you're right, and if this option was available to me I'd take it. But sometimes you can't change the schema, even though you'd like to. However I do think I'll create a view that should make the query using this table easier to write.